# Unity .GetParticles() high CPU spike

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im using .GetParticles() on a particlesystem to then destroy the particles when they are outisde of a certain range. My script is below and the particle system variable is cached. I attached the deep profile picture of what is taking the CPU and it points to GetParticles(). I can't find any documentation to why this would be a bad approach, as the script is only attached to one single game object.

Any insight appreciated, thanks!

```
private void Update()
{if (Time.time > (delayTimer + 0.02f))
    {
        delayTimer = Time.time;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Water.transform.position.y - 2f, transform.position.z);

        //Gets the change in the waters height and resets it 
        var waterHeightChange = Mathf.Abs(Water.transform.position.y - waterHeight);
        waterHeight = Water.transform.position.y;

        //Gets the distance to the top of the water to pop the bubble if surpassed 
        var DistanceToDestroy = Mathf.Abs((Water.transform.position.y + (Water.transform.localScale.y / 2f) - .15f) - transform.position.y);

        //Creates a particle array sized a the emitters maximum particles
        //Gets the particles from the emitter system and transfers into array of particles, returns total number of particles
        //Only called on occasion (once at start really) to make allocation as minimal as possible
        if (pSystemParticles == null || pSystemParticles.Length < pSystem.main.maxParticles)
        {
            pSystemParticles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[pSystem.main.maxParticles];

        }

        int numParticlesAlive = pSystem.GetParticles(pSystemParticles);

        for (int i = 0; i < numParticlesAlive; i++)
        {

            //Changes the height accordingly for each particle
            newPos.Set(pSystemParticles[i].position.x, pSystemParticles[i].position.y, pSystemParticles[i].position.z + waterHeightChange);
            //Grab the 'y' positional height relative to the emitter
            var particleHeight = newPos.z;

            if (particleHeight >= DistanceToDestroy)
            {

                //Deletes particle if needed
                pSystemParticles[i].remainingLifetime = 0;
            }
        }
        //Sets the particle system from the modified array
        pSystem.SetParticles(pSystemParticles, numParticlesAlive);
    }
}
```

[image: Script]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get this spike but this seems to be outside of your control. Maybe you could use the [Collision Module](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysCollisionModule.html), put an invisible plane above your waterline where the particles should stop and then set up the collision module such that the particles lose their whole lifetime when they collide (Lifetime Loss = 1). That way they should disappear when colliding with the plane. Could be faster because particles would never have to enter the C# world plus it's a lot less code to write.

Comment: Thanks man. Appreciate your help. Was just wondering if there was something else I was missing. Great advice, i'll look into it!